# MS Word 2007: How to hide first 4 page numbers?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, page-numbers

How can I hide the numbering of first 4 pages in MS Word 2007? I want the numbering to start from page 5 as 5, 6, 7, ...

Also, I have another related question: I insert a section break at the end of page 15 and do `Format Page Numbers --> Start at 1` to start a page numbering again from 1 after previous 15 pages. However, instead of starting from page number 1, the numbering is starting with 2. How to correct that? Thanks.

Comment: You've answered your own question. `Start at *x*` after a section break is the answer to the first part.

As for the second part of your question, you probably have a section break elsewhere, or else you have an option for a different first page set somewhere.

Comment: If you could include this as an answer then I can select it as an accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've answered your own question. "Start at *x*" after a section break is the answer to the first part.

As for the second part of your question, you probably have a section break elsewhere, or else you have an option for a different first page set somewhere.

Comment: For those looking to skip a number of pages at the beginning of a document, this guide for Word 2007 was useful to me - http://gradstudies.ucdavis.edu/students/Instructions%20for%20Word-page%20numbering%20changes%20in%20format.pdf